# Display a div if a field is true in an element of array of objects

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm writing a function to generate an array of objects as follows :

```
  setswitch() {
    for (let i = 1; i < this.assets.length; i++) {
      let cardshow = {
        id: i.toString(),
        isShow : false
      };
      this.cards.push(cardshow);
    }
  }
```

Im modifying the value of a field in array object in another function like:

```
this.cards[i]["isShow"] = true;
```

I want to use ngIf on a div based on the field value of the object.
Im trying to do this like:

```
 <div *ngFor="let notcard of notcards; index as i">
      <div class="pull-right" [ngClass]="'assetdetail'+i" *ngIf="cards[i]['isShow']">
<div>
```

This does not work. How do I get the expected result?

Comment: Where is the `i` coming from in your `ngIf` expression? If it is inside a `ngFor` then use the let reference to access the `isShow` property.

Comment: i is the index of the for loop . This div comes inside a for loop

Comment: Please reproduce the issue on stackblitz. It would be easy for everyone to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set up your provided code on Stackblitz, which btw is something that you could have done, only to discover that every line of code that you provided actually does work.

So the only reason it wouldn't work is that the notCards array used (which you didn't provide any value of) is not set up correctly.
For instance, cards cannot have a shorter array length than notCards.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2je7dr

Answer (score 1):

I'm used to writing the `ngFor` directive differently. Can you try this?

```html
<div *ngFor="let notcard of notcards; let i = index;">
    <div class="pull-right" [ngClass]="'assetdetail'+ i" *ngIf="cards[i].isShow">
<div>
```

Comment: i have slightly modified the question. My array cards is not the one looping .check my question

Answer (score 0):

From your example, I am not clear on how `notcards` is created or what is in the array... I simply initialized both the `notcards` and the `card` arrays with a `length` of `10` to ensure they match... it is important the lengths match or the logic here will not work correctly.

> Working Stackblitz example below.

I would also recommend using the following if you need to `toggle` the `div` and not just expose it.

```
card[i].isShow = !card[i].isShow
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6zfewb?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
<div *ngFor="let notcard of notcards; index as i">
    <div *ngFor="let card of cards">
        <div class="pull-right" [ngClass]="'assetdetail'+i" *ngIf="card.isShow">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i have slightly modified the question. My array cards is not the one looping .check my question

Comment: I've edited my answer please try this and let me know is it working or not as per your expectation.

Comment: this would create an array of arrays if im not wrong. I want only notcards no of items